# gulp transcompiling partially

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, babeljs

I am building a simple test (new to gulp).
my directory looks like this :

```
menu/
    js/
        node_modules/
        dist/
        es6/
        public/
            dist/
            es6/
    gulpfile.js
    .babelrc
```

gulpfile.js contains this :

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');
gulp.task('default',function(){

    gulp.src("e6/**/*.js")
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));

    gulp.src("public/es6/**/*.js")
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("public/dist"));
});
```

Then creating a test.js and run 'gulp' from  the terminal (cd to js/), I get this :

```
LEA js # gulp 
[09:29:42] Using gulpfile ~/Bureau/menu/js/gulpfile.js
[09:29:42] Starting 'default'...
[09:29:42] Finished 'default' after 8.93 ms
```

and a file js/public/dist/test.js is created that functions well (using node in terminal).

BUT : no js/dist/test.js is created. I don't see why ...

Answer (score 1):

You are missing es6 in here -> `gulp.src("e6/**/*.js")`